# Java and HTMLUnit: How to click on submit button?

Tags: java, eclipse, htmlunit, submit-button

I am brand new to Java and need to write various java applications to do web scraping and web page interaction.

I started using Selenium but because it interacts directly with a browser, it is not practical for my use.

I need to do the following tasks:
 1. Go to a specific URL
 2. Enter a post code in a input field
 3. Click submit button
 4. Parse and save results from specific div tag or re-query page.

I am using HTMLUnit and Eclipse.
I can access a webpage and enter a post code in an input by referencing the form and then the input name.
However when I try to click the submit button, I get an ElementNotFoundException error.

Here is a sample of how the submit button is implemented on the page:

```
 type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Enter post code
```

Here is what my code looks like:

```
package htmlunittest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.RefreshHandler;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlDivision;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlButtonInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;

public class htmlunittest extends TestCase{

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{

    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();            
    final HtmlPage startPage = webClient.getPage("http://www.testpage.com");

    final HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) startPage.getForms().get(2);

 final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("address");
  textField.setValueAttribute("my post code");

//throws ElementNotFoundException
  final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("submit");

// Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
System.out.println(page2.getHtmlElementById("mainContent"));

webClient.closeAllWindows();

}
}
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction as to how I should click on the submit button via HTMLUNIT?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to find out why that is not working without the whole page that you're trying to fetch.

I bet you are not getting the right form with the `.get(2)`, which by the way, is usually a bad idea to get forms that way because if the target page slightly changes its source code just to add a form above that one your scraper won't work again because the index will be different.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve store opening times from the following site: http://www.tesco.com/storeLocator/ Once I have entered the post code: SW19 8YA then I need to retrieve the store opening times.