# How to refresh page after button click in Htmlunit

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, htmlunit

I am writing a program in Java to scrape source code off a series of pages after clicking on a next button on the bottom of the page. My code is currently:

```
public class Htmlunitscraper { 

  private static String s = "http://cpdocket.cp.cuyahogacounty.us/SheriffSearch/results.aspx?q=searchType%3dSaleDate%26searchString%3d10%2f21%2f2013%26foreclosureType%3d%27NONT%27%2c+%27PAR%27%2c+%27COMM%27%2c+%27TXLN%27";

  public static String scrapeWebsite() throws IOException {

    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(s);
    final HtmlForm form = page.getForms().get(0);
    final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByValue(">");
    final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
    int amountOfTries = 10;
    while (amountOfTries > 0 && String originalHtml = page2.getWebResponse().getContentAsString() !=page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString()) {
    amountOfTries--;
    synchronized (page) {
        page.wait(1000);
    }
   }
    return originalHtml;
  }
}
```

This is the first time I have used Htmlunit, so I have been referring to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061533/java-and-htmlunit-how-to-click-on-submit-button). For starters, I am not exactly sure how the class "Form" works, and what exactly it does. For my issue though, the string that is being printed is the source code from the original webpage, not after the next button has been clicked. When viewing the source manually from the URL, once I click the next button, I have to refresh the page to view the updated source code, so imagine I will have to emulate this in my program. How would I go about doing this? Even after adding the refresh method it is still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webpage is actually using AJAX, so clicking on the button doesn't get you to a new page. The HTTP request happens in the background and once it is finished the DOM in the page is refreshed. However, you need to wait for that to happen and it seems you're not doing so.

Refer to this [link](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#AJAXDoesNotWork) to see how to process AJAX request in HTMLUnit.

Comment: Mosty, If I wanted to implement the method "webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000)" how would this work because currently I am clicking the button to get a new HtmlPage, not a new webClient.

Comment: See this [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843521/get-the-changed-html-content-after-its-updated-by-javascript-htmlunit). I've added an answer there that might be useful.

Comment: Would the edited code be the correct way of implementing my condition?

Comment: No. You need to find the condition yourself. In AJAX things change usually based on IDs. You will have to check what changes in that specific page after the AJAX call is completed and that will be your condition. Most likely, will be very similar to the one I pasted in the other question (EG: checking if something turn from `Loading...` to something else)

Comment: Would I find this change using something such as firebug?

Comment: That is correct. You should also read about AJAX (look for some tutorial online and that will help you a lot).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39853/discussion-between-connor-and-mosty-mostacho)

Answer (score 0):

actually u put wrong url  ...
   pls open url first manually  then you can see that http://cpdocket.cp.cuyahogacounty.us/SheriffSearch/results.aspx?q=searchType%3dSaleDate%26searchString%3d10%2f21%2f2013%26foreclosureType%3d%27NONT%27%2c+%27PAR%27%2c+%27COMM%27%2c+%27TXLN%27

then we got the error like 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
pls check it first.